# Attempt to read property "created_at" on null

Tags: php, laravel

I need to output the creation date, but sometimes there may not be a date, for this I did in blade.php `@forelse`, but it doesn't help

**Controller**

```
        $dataBumps[] = DB::table('server_user_likes')
            ->where('server_id', $server->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->first();
```

**blade.php**

```
    @forelse ($dataBumps as $dataBump)
        {{$dataBump->created_at}}
    @empty
    -
    @endforelse
```

Comment: _SOmetimes there is no date in `created_at`_ Hmmm that does not sound good. Specially as you are ordering desc and only picking the first result? Hmmmm, wouldn't that suggest they are all null?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the ```server_user_likes table``` is a rating table, and there may not be a rating, and, accordingly, the dates.

Comment: You are calling the `first()` then you can not loop the result. because you'll get only one object. if `created_at` is empty, that means maybe it's NULL. can you confirm you have a value for `created_at` from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing also null values into the array.

You can try to `dd($dataBumps);` to debug it and add a check in your blade file.
A simple example

```
@forelse ($dataBumps as $dataBump)
@if ($dataBump !== null)
    {{$dataBump->created_at}}
@else
    -
@endif
```

@empty
-
@endforelse

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. It's even a shame that I didn't think of such a simple solution myself))

Comment: Great to hear, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. Feel free to upvote it and mark it as correct for other users @CARSAR